# Insert csv file data into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a csv file that is having 199000 records and I want to insert it into mysql table but when I run the code to insert the data  its shows error that it take a more than 30 seconds for execution so for in this case what have to done

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: $csv_file=CSV_PATH."file.csv";$csvfile=fopen($csv_file, 'r');
$theData=fgets($csvfile);
$i=0;

while(!feof($csvfile))
{
$csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile,1024);
$csv_array=explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
$insert_csv=array();
$insert_csv['name']=$csv_array[0];
$insert_csv['address']='http://'.$csv_array[1];
$insert_csv['duns_number']=$csv_array[2];
$insert_csv['idnum']=$csv_array[3];

$query="insert into companyinfo(name,address,duns_number,id_number)values('".$insert_csv['name']."','".$insert_csv['address']."','".$insert_csv['duns_number']."','".$insert_csv['idnum']."')";

++$i;
}

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_time_limit(0)` before running any code. This way you can reset this 30 seconds execution time limit.

Comment: where to use this set_time_limit(0) in a code means use  inside the loop or outside the loop

Comment: @VijaySharma outside. Before any code. Ok, it should be like a first line or something.

Comment: thanks I have insert the fuction outside at the starting of the code

Comment: I have run the code it will fetch the record from the csv file to insert into table  but it will not each and every record for example it fetch the record from 23637 row instead from first row from the file why is it so I will send you also the code if you want.

Comment: please answer the uestion that I have asked you above.

Answer (score 0):

```
string fgets ( resource $handle [, int $length ] )
```

> **length**
>   Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, or a newline (which is included in the return value), or an EOF (whichever comes first)

Your code

```
fgets($csvfile,1024)
```

EOF is after 1024 bytes

change it to

```
 fgets($csvfile,4096)
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a very usefull function called LOAD DATA INFILE [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html)